# Why are disabled UISegmentedControl segments drawn incorrectly on iOS 4.0+?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uisegmentedcontrol

For some strange reason, on iOS 4.2.1 (and any iPhone OS after 4.0), using a UISegmentedControl as a UIBarButtonItem in a toolbar will leave disabled segments drawn incorrectly, like this:

[image]

The text is displayed in dark gray, but should resemble the disabled state of the disabled "Login" button in the upper right. I'm using a standard UISegmentedControl, not a subclass.

Is there any way to get around this bug?

UPDATE: It's definitely not supposed to look that way and is probably a regression indroduced in iOS 4.0. Here's how it looks on 3.1.3:

[image]

Comment: Not sure it's a bug. Look at enabled "Previous" and "Cancel" buttons, they look pretty different, too.